# Columns of Tabular on Different Slides (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, tables, columns

I would like to show a tabular by columns for didactical reasons.

Example:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Beispiel & Erklärung \\\hline
Die Schule fällt Fritzchen nicht leicht. & Unterricht\\
Fritzchen geht in die Schule. & Ort\\
Die Schule muss reformiert werden. & System\\
Die Schule muss renoviert werden. & Gebäude\\
\end{tabular}
```

I would like first to show the column "Beispiel" (maybe with slides seperated by `\pause`) and on one of the following slides I would like to show the "Erklärung" column (again, maybe seperated). Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: This is documented in [section 23.6 of the `beamer` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#section.23.6).

Answer (score 6):

One suggestion can seen below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{l<{\onslide<+->}l<{\onslide<+->}}
Beispiel & Erklärung \\\hline
Die Schule fällt Fritzchen nicht leicht. & Unterricht\\
Fritzchen geht in die Schule. & Ort\\
Die Schule muss reformiert werden. & System\\
Die Schule muss renoviert werden. & Gebäude\\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{l<{\pause}l<{\pause}}
Beispiel & Erklärung \\\hline
Die Schule fällt Fritzchen nicht leicht. & Unterricht\\
Fritzchen geht in die Schule. & Ort\\
Die Schule muss reformiert werden. & System\\
Die Schule muss renoviert werden. & Gebäude\\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**

Philip asked in the comment below:

> Do you by chance know how to do the same but show first the line
>   "Beispiel Erklärung" and afterwards the remaining entries columnwise?

You can set every row as a tabular.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\everyrow{\pause}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Beispiel & Erklärung \\\hline\pause
 \begin{tabular}{@{}l<{\pause}@{}}
   Die Schule fällt Fritzchen nicht leicht. \\
   Fritzchen geht in die Schule.\\
   Die Schule muss reformiert werden. \\
   Die Schule muss renoviert werden.  
 \end{tabular}
 &
 \begin{tabular}{@{}l<{\pause}@{}}
   Unterricht\\
   Ort\\
   System\\
   Gebäude
 \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You seem to be quite good with the tabular. Do you by chance know how to do the same but show first the line "Beispiel  Erklärung" and afterwards the remaining entries columnwise?

Comment: @Philip: A small example is given in my edit.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Wonderful solution to Philip's comment. Exactly what I was searching for. However, after the entire table is gradually uncovered, the whole thing is repeated once more (that is, I have one extra slide that adds nothing). Is there a simple way to avoid this?